# How to resolve this image resize error in php? Beginner

Tags: php, image

I am trying to resize an image on the server side. I am getting the image but when I am trying to resize the image; it is throwing some error. Here is what I have done:

imgresize.php: **This file creates the resized image.**

```
<?php
function compressImage($ext, $uploadedfile, $actual_image_name, $newwidth)
{

  if($ext=="jpg" || $ext=="jpeg" ){
    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);

      list($width,$height)=getimagesize($uploadedfile);

      $newheight=($height/$width)*$newwidth;

      $tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);
      imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);

    //  $filename = $newwidth.'_'.$actual_image_name; //PixelSize_TimeStamp.jpg
      $filename = $actual_image_name; //PixelSize_TimeStamp.jpg

      imagejpeg($tmp,$filename,100);

      imagedestroy($tmp);
  }
  else if($ext=="png"){
    $src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);

    list($width,$height)=getimagesize($uploadedfile);

    $newheight=($height/$width)*$newwidth;

    $tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);
    imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);

  //  $filename = $newwidth.'_'.$actual_image_name; //PixelSize_TimeStamp.jpg
    $filename = $actual_image_name; //PixelSize_TimeStamp.jpg

    imagepng($tmp,$filename,100);

    imagedestroy($tmp);
  }
  else{

  }
  return $filename;
}
?>
```

Here is my code to get it in my server-side:

```
include 'imgresize.php';
if($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'] != ''){

            $tmp_name_array = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
            $uploadedImageName = $_FILES['img']['name'][0];

            $imageName = htmlspecialchars($_FILES['img']['tmp_name']);
            $imgSize = $_FILES['img']['size'];
            //$name= htmlspecialchars($_FILES['img']['name']);
            print_r($_FILES['img']);

            $tempImgName = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
            if(strlen($tempImgName)){
                $ext = pathinfo($tempImgName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                if(in_array($ext, $valid_formats)){
                    if($imgSize < 2*1024*1024){

                        $imageName = compressImage($ext, $tempImgName, $tempImgName, 200);
                        $imageContents = file_get_contents($imageName);
                        $encodedImage = base64_encode($imageContents);

                        array_push($uploadImage, $encodedImage);

                        // database query


} else{
                        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">".
                            "window.alert('Image size should be less than 2MB.');".
                            "window.location.href='edit-profile.php?id=".$id."';".
                            "</script>";
                    }
                } else{
                    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">".
                            "window.alert('Invalid image extension found. (Image should be of jpg, jpeg, png extension only) ');".
                            "window.location.href='edit-profile.php?id=".$id."';".
                            "</script>";
                }

            }
```

It gives me the following error:

```
[24-Feb-2016 18:47:50 Etc/GMT] PHP Warning:  imagecreatefromjpeg(11150825_10153266879053764_3215821412576026934_n.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/user/public_html/utils/imgresize.php on line 6
[24-Feb-2016 18:47:50 Etc/GMT] PHP Warning:  getimagesize(11150825_10153266879053764_3215821412576026934_n.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/user/public_html/utils/imgresize.php on line 15
[24-Feb-2016 18:47:50 Etc/GMT] PHP Warning:  Division by zero in /home/user/public_html/utils/imgresize.php on line 17
[24-Feb-2016 18:47:50 Etc/GMT] PHP Warning:  imagecreatetruecolor(): Invalid image dimensions in /home/prernnys/public_html/utils/imgresize.php on line 19
[24-Feb-2016 18:47:50 Etc/GMT] PHP Warning:  imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/prernnys/user/utils/imgresize.php on line 20
[24-Feb-2016 18:47:50 Etc/GMT] PHP Warning:  imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/user/public_html/utils/imgresize.php on line 25
[24-Feb-2016 18:47:50 Etc/GMT] PHP Warning:  imagedestroy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/user/public_html/utils/imgresize.php on line 27
[24-Feb-2016 18:47:50 Etc/GMT] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(11150825_10153266879053764_3215821412576026934_n.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/user/public_html/update.php on line 916
```

The image is not getting resized as expected. Please correct me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is generated because the $tempImgName you're passing inside compressImage function is not a real file in your server folder but just a cache file (11150825_10153266879053764_3215821412576026934_n.jpg).
To fix this error, just use `$imageName = compressImage($ext, $tempImgName, $tempImgName, 200);` passing the real path of the image. Probably $uploadedImageName is the correct one to use

Comment: Yes. You are correct Sonny. However, I get the file contents using file_get_contents($_file['img']). How can I further resize it?.. I was planning to use TinyPng api but later thought to do it by myself. Hence the above situation.

Comment: I think you have 2 options available here. The first is saving the file first, resize the image and overwrite the file. The second is using the temp file generated on the server side, resizing and and saving the image in the desired path. Using the second option you will need to know where the temp files are stored on your server side first. Have a look at the php documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php

Comment: When I try to work with the temp file generated on server side; it has no extension so the image never gets resized.

Comment: ok then: create another temporary folder; save the file in that folder first; resize the image; save the resized image in your destination folder; then destroy the temporary fodler

Comment: I have to do this for atleast 200-5000 users. Do you think this is a feasible solution? What if two users file-names are same? Then I am done! :D However, I will try that.

Comment: I think you will have to deal with the same, duplicate names issue, also in your final destination folder. I suggest to rename the temporary files, at least, using a random MD5 hash like this: `md5(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)))`